# Python CGI with IIS6 returns a 404 error

Tags: iis-6, python

I'm trying to get Python 2.7 working as a CGI script in IIS6. I do this all the time on W2k8, but this is the first time I've tried to use it on IIS6 and I cannot get it to work. Googling suggests just two steps are needed:

1. Create the Web Service Extension
2. Add a mapping for .py

I've done both of these but when I try to open a test.py page I get a 404 error. There must be something simple I'm missing. Any suggestions gratefully received while I still have some hair left!

I'm testing on a new install of W2k3R2 so there is nothing extra like URLScan or AV that might be interfering.

I created the Web Service Extension using:

[image: WSE]

I'm using Python in a virtual directory, and the directory properties are:

[image: DirectoryProps]

And finally the mapping is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the additional steps to map your D: Python executable as a CGI, documented on [David Wang's MSN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/04/20/iis6-cgi-web-service-extension.aspx)

Comment: Hi Mike, I had already seen that article and gone through the steps it described. Anyhow, I thought I'd have one more go, and it worked! I don't know what I did wrong the first time, but anyhow the bounty is yours (in 22 hours when SE allows me to grant it :-)

Comment: I've set myself an Outlook reminder :-) It appears SE doesn't allow me to award the bonus until 24 hours after I created it, so I'll have to do it tomorrow.